# How do I include feature names in the plot_tree function from the XGBoost library?

Tags: python, xgboost

I've been using the [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to develop a binary classification model. Having trained my model I am interested in visualizing the individual trees to better understand my models predictions.

To do this XGBoost provides a [plot_tree](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.plot_tree) function but it only shows the integer index of the feature. Here is an example of one of my trees:

[image]

How do I include the feature name in this image rather than feature index (`f28`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `plot_tree` function  in xgboost has an argument `fmap` which is a path to a 'feature map' file; this contains a mapping of the feature index to feature name.

The documentation on the feature map file is sparse, but it is  a tab-delimited file where the first column is the feature indices (starting from 0 and ending at the number of features), the second column the feature name and the final column an indicator showing the type of feature (q=quantitative feature, i=binary feature).

An example of a `feature_map.txt` file:

```
0    feature_name_0    q
1    feature_name_1    i
2    feature_name_2    q
…          …           …
```

With this tab-delimited file you can then plot your tree from your trained model instance:

```
import xgboost
model = xgboost.XGBClassifier()

# train the model
model.fit(X, y)

# plot the decision tree, providing path to feature map file

xgboost.plot_tree(model,  num_trees=0, fmap='feature_map.txt')
```

Using this function displays the plot:

[image]

Comment: For more complicated pipelines (e.g. feature union between categorical, numerical and passthrough columns), how do we get this mapping?  I tried extracting them from the feature pipeline, then writing to disk as such `fmap.to_csv(DATA_DIR / Path('feature-map.txt'), sep="\t", header=False)`, but no luck

Answer (score 2):

I found that the easiest way is to set the feature names on the model directly. Obviously, the order needs to be correct.

```
model = XGBClassifier()    
model.get_booster().feature_names = feature_names # As a list or tuple!
```

Afterwards, the feature names will appear with the plot_tree function.

Comment: This works but you need to fit the model first

Comment: If using this from 'xgb' and not scikit, load your booster model as bst and set bst.feature_names= ['array','of','features']

Comment: The way I'm using it is `model.get_booster().feature_names = list(X.columns)`. Works well and it's straightforward to do.