# What are the possible feature types in xgboost?

Tags: xgboost

On the documentation page for xgboost for python we see a `feature_types` https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html parameters but have no idea what are the possible values.

The documentation is really bad.

What are the possible values for `feature_types`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation seems poor as you say, [searching through the XGBoost source code on Github](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/search?q=feature_types) gives some tests that show these options:

- int
- float
- q: quantitative
- i: indicator

While it is a bit difficult to figure out what these mean, some other sites list some additional information:

- i: "[i means this feature is binary indicator feature](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/xgboost.html)"
- q: "[means this feature is a quantitative value, such as age, time, can be missing](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/xgboost.html)"
- int: "[means this feature is integer value (when int is hinted, the decision boundary will be integer)](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/xgboost.html)"

Link: [another StackOverflow post that mentions the q and i types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60186747/how-do-i-include-feature-names-in-the-plot-tree-function-from-the-xgboost-librar).

In XGBoosts [core.py](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/dee5ef2dfdd80c3d6744d3f86e971dac5c03b1d4/python-package/xgboost/core.py) code you can also find a comment on types:

```
 # use quantitative as default
 # {'q': quantitative, 'i': indicator}
```

Looking at the XGBoost code, from the rest of it, the type parsing goes into the underlying c-based backend code, so that is a bit of a black box still unless you want to go explore it.. :)